# How is sizeof(char *) and sizeof(char) different?

Tags: c, string, pointers, sizeof

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    char *str[]= {"Frogs","do","not","die","they","croak"};
    printf("%d %d %d",sizeof(str),sizeof(str[0]),sizeof(char));
}
```

output is:

> 48 8 1

According to size of `char` being `1` byte and there are six character variables so total size of array should be `6` instead of `48`!

Comment: Yes I am using 64 bit system

Comment: As you are on 64bit you should not print `size_t` typed "values" using the `d`  conversion specifier, as this expects `int` which probably is 32bit wide, as opposed to `size_t` which is expected to be 64bit wide.

Comment: Why would you expect that `sizeof(T)` is the same as `sizeof(T *)`? They are different types, why should their size be equal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Point 1**

`sizeof` retruns the *size* of the data type, not the amount of memory allocated to the variable.

For what it's worth, if you want to measure the *length* of a *string*, (i.e., the number of elements inside a string), you can use [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)

**Point 2**

Don't get confused with the datatypes.

- `str` is an array of pointers. It holds `6` pointers, so the `sizeof` will give `6 * sizeof(<pointer type>)` which is `6 * 8` or `48` on 64-bit systems.
- `str[0]` is a pointer, so `sizeof str[0]` equals `sizeof(char *)` which is `8` on 64-bit systems.
- `C` standard guarantees `sizeof(char)` to be equal to `1`.

**Point 3**

`sizeof` operator returns a `size_t`. You need to use `%zu` format specifier to print that portably and reliably.

Answer (score 3):

`str` is a length-6 array of pointers to `char`. Its total size is 6 times the size of a pointer, which gives 48 on your platform.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're on a 64-bit system, where `sizeof (char *)` is 8.

This explains the first value, since `sizeof str` is the size of the object `str`, which has type `char *[6]`. So you're getting the size as 48, which is of course 6 * 8.

Also, the proper way to `printf()` values of type `size_t`, which is what `sizeof` returns, is with `%zu`.

Answer (score 2):

The `printf` format specifier `%d` is inappropriate for the argument values `sizeof(str)` and `sizeof(str[0])` whose type is `size_t`.

You should either use `%zu` or cast the arguments as `(int)`.

There are more problems with your code:

- the return type for `main` must be specified as `int`.
- the type of `str` should be `const char *str[]`.
- You should add a `\n` to the printf format to ensure that output id properly flushed on all systems.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    const char *str[] = { "Frogs", "do", "not", "die", "they", "croak" };
    printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof(str), sizeof(str[0]));
}
```

It should output `24 4` or `48 8` on respectively 32 bit and 64 bit systems, and potentially other values on more exotic systems. The first number is the size of 6 pointers to `const char` and the second, the size of a single such pointer.

The size of the strings themselves can be determined at compile for constant immediate strings and defined arrays only as direct arguments of `sizeof`.  In other cases, you must use `strlen()` to compute the string length, assuming they do not contain embedded NULs, and add 1 for the final `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

An array declared like

```
char *str[]={"Frogs","do","not","die","they","croak"};
```

has type `char *[6]`. that is it is an aray of 6 pointers to characters. Consequently `str[0]` has type `char *` that is it is a pointer.

Thus

```
sizeof( str[0] )
```

is equivalent to

```
sizeof( char * )
```

and in your system is equal to 8.

In turn

```
sizeof ( str )
```

is equivalent to

```
6 * sizeof( char * )
```

and equal to 48.

Take into account that in this initializer list

```
char *str[]={"Frogs","do","not","die","they","croak"};
```

string literals are implicitly converted to pointers to their first characters.

On the other hand if you will write for example

```
sizeof( "Frogs" )
```

then the expression will be equal to 6 becuase 1) string literals are character arrays that include terminating zero and 2) within the operator sizeof they are not implicitly converted to pointers to their first characters, they are considered as arrays.

You could define a two dimensional array of strings the following way

```
char str[][6] = { "Frogs", "do", "not", "die", "they", "croak" };
```

In this case

```
sizeof( str[0] )
```

would be equal to 6 and

```
sizeof( str )
```

would be equal to 36 because in this case `str` is an array of elements of type `char [6]`

Pay attention to that in the last case you may change elements of the array the following way

```
str[0][0] = 'f';
```

while when you have an array of pointers to string literals (as in your original post) you may not write

```
str[0][0] = 'f';
```

because string literals are immutable.

And one more about the `sizeof` operator. According to the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (**in bytes**) of its operand,
>   which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The
>   size is determined from the type of the operand. The result is an
>   integer. If the type of the operand is a variable length array type,
>   the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and
>   the result is an integer constant.

Thus being applied to an array the operator yields the number of bytes the array occupies. It does not yield the number of elements in the array. If you want to get the number of elements in an array you should use expression

```
sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[0] )
```

or

```
sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array )
```

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh Thanks, it was a typo.